# How do I calculate correlation in python Only the first 9 columns and the iloc function are to be used corr_matrix = dataset.iloc[:,0:8].corr()

Tags: python, correlation

What should go in the corr () argument?
The idea is to used column parameters from 0 to 8 to find correlation

corr_matrix = dataset.iloc[:,0:8].corr()

The problem is using iloc with corr

Comment: What is the issue exactly? I don't see a problem with `df.iloc[0,:8].corr()`.

Comment: Nothing should go inside `corr()`, this is similar to writing `corr(dataset.iloc[:,0:8])`.

Comment: it is not working The given answer should be something like:  corr_matrix = dataset.iloc[:,0:8].______   Im wondering what should replace the underlined blank

Comment: with corr_matrix = dataset.iloc[:,0:8].corr(), I get NameError: name 'dataset' is not defined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does the following work for you?:

```
subset = dataset[["col1_name","col2_name", ..., "col8name"]] 
corr_matrix = subset.corr()
```

Comment: We have no idea what the user's problem is yet.

Comment: Yes, this one works but I am doing an assignment where I have to demonstrate the use of the iloc function.